# GoogleAppEngine Java Captcha without external providers

Tags: java, google-app-engine, awt, captcha, simplecaptcha

Is there any library for captcha generation which does not contain blacklisted classes ?

I would like to avoid to use recaptcha.

I tried JCaptcha and SimpleCaptcha but both use AWT for image generation.

The google ticket http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1423&q=awt&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log has been accepted 1 year ago but we don't have news about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found http://code.google.com/p/litetext/ which works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The Java runtime doesn't currently have any support for image manipulation, short of writing your own decode/encode/pixel-bitbashing code. You're unlikely to find any tools that do their own image manipulation rather than using AWT.

Your best option is to use an external service.